# VBA ClearContents method clearing items in collection

Tags: excel, vba, collections

Can someone explain to me why .Cells.ClearContents method clears items in collection?
I run following code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim i As Integer    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 1 To 10
            col.Add .Cells(i, 1)
        Next i
        MsgBox (col(1) & " " & col.Count)
        .Cells.ClearContents
        MsgBox (col(1) & " " & col.Count)
    End With
End Sub
```

Cells from A1 to A10 contains letters, eg. a,b,c...
The first msgbox shows "a 10" and the secondone "10". Why is this happening and what is the way to clear whole worksheet without clearing the collection?

Comment: `col.Add .Cells(i, 1).Value`. I find it easier to use an array here than a collection: `Dim arr`, `arr = Worksheets("Sheet1).Range("A1:A10").Value`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this code is only an example to show the problem with ClearContents method. Originally I'm importing over 2 mln rows to collection, making some operation on this collection and then, I want to put the records back do worksheet, which should be cleared first.

Comment: As I mentioned - probably easier to use an array but in any case work with the `.Value` of the range.

Comment: For my scenario it's easier to work with collection. But this is not a point. I'm asking why .Cells.ClearContents method of Woksheet object is clearing items in collection along with cells in worksheet and how to avoid this.

Comment: How to avoid this: work with the `.Value` of the `Range`.

Comment: In other words, the collection contains a pointer to the original cell.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are building a Collection of `Ranges` not a Collection of numbers or text strings.

If you enter a Range,*(like Range("A1"))* into the collection, you are not freezing it.  If you change **A1**'s value in the worksheet, when it item is drawn out, it will reflect the change:

```
Sub CollectionTest()
    Dim col As Collection, rng As Range
    Set col = New Collection

    Range("A1").Clear
    col.Add Range("A1")
    Range("A1").Value = "x"
    Set rng = col.Item(1)

    MsgBox rng.Value
End Sub
```

That is why you should Collect the `Value`s rather than the `Range`s themselves.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I get it!

Comment: @Stripe  Although it is not accurate, you can think of a `Collection` as a set of pointers to the objects that have been collected.